# No option for booting into ubuntu when sharing drive with windows 7

Tags: dual-boot

Using the 12.04 install DVD I installed ubuntu on the same drive as windows.  It is defaulting to windows each time.  How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows is greedy and rewrites the master boot record to only point to itself, making it so that it bypasses GRUB and Ubuntu.  Typically, Ubuntu should be installed after Windows, but it's okay.

Burn [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) .iso to a disk and load and run it after Windows is installed. It'll restore the boot log and you'll see GRUB again and everything should be happy.

Comment: I installed ubuntu after windows was present.  Should I still do what you suggest?

Comment: is there anyway to put this on a thumb drive instead?

Comment: Yes, and yes.  Since it seems Windows is working for you, use this tool http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ to take the .iso you've downloaded and stick it on a usb.  Here's some offical documentation which conveniently recommends the same thing.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair